# Visit algorithm used by Neo4j

Tags: algorithm, graph, neo4j, dijkstra

I read in Neo4j docs that "*Neo4j comes with a number of built-in graph algorithms*". 
When I make a query using *Cipher*, which is the default visit algorithm of the oriented graph? Is it Djikstra?

For example, this query:

```
MATCH(n1)-[r]->(n2)
RETURN n1
```

returns all edges that point to other edges using any relationship.
But which is the algorithm that Neo4j used to visit all edges and arcs involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefix your query with PROFILE you see the operations that are executed by Cypher to run your query. There is no single algorithm it is an emergent behavior out of the planned operations.

See also: http://neo4j.com/blog/introducing-new-cypher-query-optimizer/

Answer (score 2):

The graph algorithms that are referenced in that documentation section refer to some of the classic graph algorithms that have been around for decades, as part of graph research.  Specifically, they're talking about the Dijkstra algorithm, shortest path, and all shortest path.

The query you list doesn't use any of those algorithms.  The algorithm that is used in this case is just what I'd call the implementation of cypher.  I don't think returning these particular nodes is any broadly identified graph algorithm per se.